# Contact form html

Tags: html, forms

i am designing a contact page for a friend he gave me a templete to use for his site it has a contact page already built in with the following code

```
<td><form method="post" action="/frms/contactmail.pl">
        <input type="hidden" name="SoupermailConf" value="/frms/contact.con">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                  <td align="Right"><b>Your 
                    Name: <span class="style1">*</span></b></td>
                  <td width="70%"><input type="TEXT" name="Name" style="width: 90%;">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="Right"><b>E-mail 
                    Address: <span class="style1">*</span></b></td>
                  <td><input type="TEXT" name="Name2" style="width: 90%;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="Right"><b>Company:</b></td>
                  <td><input type="TEXT" name="Name3" style="width: 90%;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="Right"><b>How 
                    did you 
                    find us?</b></td>
                  <td><input type="TEXT" name="Name4" style="width: 90%;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="right"><b> Questions: <span class="style1">* </span></b></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" align="center"><textarea name="Question" rows="8" style="width: 90%;" wrap="VIRTUAL"></textarea>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form">
                      <br>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

I do not see where there is an action or mailto command how do i need to change this to make it email to a specific email address.

Comment: Your code is missing.  please edit your question and add it in,

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Check for PHP / Other Pages other than HTML.

Comment: i had an issue did not realize i need to space it 4 times lol new to the site sorry

Comment: Is this everything you have?  You are missing a large amount.  To correctly display code, highlight it all and press CTRL+K

Comment: in the web templete that i was given there is no pages other than html no php or java pages

Comment: this is just the code for the submit button i can post the rest of the code for the form if you would like to see it as well

Comment: Yes please post it all.

Comment: there it is now i see the action button at the top not use to seeing it there thought is that what i should change to mailto:xxxxxx@gmail.com with the <td><form method="post" action="/frms/contactmail.pl">

Comment: Can you also include the code for the file `/frms/contactmail.pl` as this is where the mail() function should be.  .pl seems odd though...

Comment: @Nico — [Don't use `mailto:` as a form action. It doesn't work.](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) You need a server side program to handle the form data (and that can send the email). That could be a Perl program at the URL you have already specified.

Comment: why does mailto not work I have used in the past without problems. is there something different about this as the templete he has given me only has HMTL pages in it no other scripts or programs contained in the zip file as far as the code for the /frms/contactmail.pl that was what was written into the templete there is no other code i see that has a pl extension on it

Comment: @Nico — There is a link in my previous comment. Try reading it. You might have used it in the past without experiencing problems, that doesn't mean that a large proportion of visitors to your site didn't have problems: If it didn't work then you simply wouldn't get any email from them.

Comment: @Nico — If you don't have a server side form mailer program, then you need to either find one or write one (ensuring that it is either compatible with your existing hosting plan or changing your plan to a compatible one at the same time).

Comment: he is going to be using hostgator which my past dealings with were to say the least not very usefull so i guess i can just use a mailer templete for him and input the html from there unless you all have a better suggestion

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the `<form>` tag, the specified action is a Perl/CGI script - `"/frms/contactmail.pl"`.

Looking at the hidden field named "SoupermailConf", I'd guess this is using the (VERY old) Perl/CGI script [Soupermail](http://soupermail.sourceforge.net/manual.html).

I would recommend you update to something else (perhaps PHP based) if you (or your friend) can?

But, if you cant then according to the [manual](http://soupermail.sourceforge.net/manual.html) a hidden field named `Email` should do the trick.

`<input type="hidden" name="Email" value="someone@your.website" />`

Comment: if you look at the new code i laced above it has the form tag in it unless i am not following you

Comment: @Nico, True, didn't see the new code straight away. Have updated the answer!

Comment: if it was using a perl or cgi script i should see that script somewhere in the zip file but again there is nothing there but HTML files

Comment: Ah, well in that case you (thankfully) will be forced into updating to something.. Or I suppose you could try to setup Soupermail on your friends webserver (bad idea).

Comment: ok so this templete from what i was reading from the manual page is missing a config file for the mailer so it is really a mute point without that file unless i write one for it correct?

Comment: Yes, you would need the hidden Email field (which will get SPAMMED as it's plaintext in HTML), the configuration file AND the Soupermail CGI script all setup on your server.  Hence my recommendation to upgrade to something else ;)

Comment: what would you recomend upgrading too

Comment: Well, if your server supports it PHP is the in-vouge technology for this sort of thing these days.  Otherwise (if you only have Perl) you'd need to look for another Perl/CGI script.  Note that PHP scripts can also be run through CGI, so your server *should* handle it.

Answer (score -1):

After looking at the manul pages for the mailer and some examples for the config.txt file I needed to write to make it work.

Comment: I'm sure the next person who has the same problem will appreciate you not giving your solution to the problem.

Comment: I did give the solution I stated that by reading the manual on the Mailer's website it gave me the instructions on what to write for the config file please take the time to read all comments before posting

Comment: What is "the Mailer's web site"? Telling us the solution is elsewhere, a third-party, is not allowed on SO. You don't show your solution.

Comment: @Rob I think "the Mailer's web site" means the [Soupermail manual page](http://soupermail.sourceforge.net/manual.html) that I [linked in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119923/contact-form-html/35120070#35120070).